# Questions with or without it in a song

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

I have a question about a song I heard…
There is a part where it says:
Is it the look in your eyes? Or Is it this dancing juice?
And my questions is: Why do they use “it”? Shouldn’t it be without “it”?
The song is: Marry you-Bruno Mars
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think yes, so they used “it” to emphasize?

Comment: I think a got it, they are using “it” just for grammatical rules, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It" in this line refers to the (unknown) reason the singer wants to "marry you". If you removed "it" from the sentence, the sentence would have a very different meaning (or no meaning).

In normal conversation, that line would be a little confusing because it's not clear what the pronoun "it" refers to. But in love songs, it's very common for the singer to speculate about the reason for their attraction. "Is it because you are beautiful? Is it because you are a good dancer? Is it because I am lonely? Is it because I am drunk?" Because this line is in the context of a love song, it's clear to the listener that Bruno Mars' desire to marry is the general subject of the song, and that questions like "Is it the look in your eyes?" are asking why *this* woman or *this* night is special.

In contrast, here are the sentences without the word "it":

> Is the look in your eyes?

This is a question about *whether or not* the look is in your eyes. (The word "is" is moved to the beginning of the sentence to indicate a question.)

> Is the dancing juice?

This sentence does not make sense without a lot more context. A fluent speaker would only use it as an (elliptical) continuation of a pattern, such as:  "Is the food ready? Is the music ready? Is the lighting [ready]? Is the dancing juice [ready]?" However, without a pattern to fill in the missing part of the sentence, "Is the dancing juice?" does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much! So, this doesn't have something to do with the “dummy it” right?

Comment: That's right. I do not think this is a "dummy it", because "it" does refer to something.

Comment: Thank you so much!